# Does /setworldspawn affect /spawnpoint?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I `/setworldspawn`, and then `/spawnpoint`, will the player's spawn point be at the location where `/setworldspawn` or `/spawnpoint` was set?

Comment: Are these vanilla commands? Or is this a mod/bukkit?

Comment: @Unionhawk `/setworldspawn` is new in 1.7, `/setspawn` has been around in vanilla for a while.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Aaaaahhh... It's `/spawnpoint`. That's what was going wrong on my end.

Comment: @Unionhawk Ah! I need to fix that then. Good eye. ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This depends on who "the player" you're talking about is. The important thing is that the world spawn and a player's spawn are entirely separate things, and these commands each affect one of those, but not the other.

`/setworldspawn` moves the spawn point encoded in the world: this is where new players and players whose spawn points are invalid (e.g., broken or blocked beds) are spawned. Any player with a valid spawn point already set elsewhere will be unaffected.

`/spawnpoint` changes *your* spawn point, just as if you'd used a bed.

So the result of typing `/setworldspawn` then `/spawnpoint` would be to change the default spawn point of the world to the coordinates you specified in the first command, and then set *your* spawnpoint to the coordinates you specified in the second command.

If by "the player" you mean anyone else, then what will happen depends on whether they already have a spawn point set with a bed or with `/spawnpoint`:

- If they don't already have their own spawnpoint, their spawnpoint becomes the new world spawnpoint.
- If they do already have their own spawnpoint, nothing changes for that player.

Comment: Note: `/spawnpoint` can set the spawn location for any player, not just that of the player using it. The player you specify needs to be on the server at the time, and you need to be an operator on the server to do it.

Comment: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#setworldspawn

Comment: one thing that is unclear to me - can you set the world spawn point for the end and nether this way?

Comment: @michael That would be a good new question. You should [Ask it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!